# Express form post not working

Tags: node.js, forms, express, ejs

I've an EJS page with a search box form. This page also contains JQuery, Bootstrap files. I don't know if it's a problem.

```
<form action="/s" method="post">
     <input type="text" name="q" title="search">
     <input type="submit" value="search">
</form>
```

app.js:

```
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');

app.use(favicon(path.join(__dirname, 'public', 'favicon.ico')));
app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: false}));
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

app.post('/s', function(req, res){
    console.log('Searching...');
});
```

Clicking the submit button is not triggering anything. I don't know what is the problem. Can anyone help me? Thank you.

**Edit:**
 I've three ejs template inlcudes on this page.

```
<% include partials/head %> 
<% include partials/header %> 
<% include partials/footer %>
```

If I remove all these three it's working.

Comment: Should you not have something like `<input type="text" name="q" value="">`?

Comment: Adding value="" isn't making any difference.

Comment: So if you type in a value and hit submit, nothing happens? You don't get any message in your node console? Try adding `res.send('POST successful')` in your `'/'` route.

Comment: Nope, nothing.  I've three ejs template `<% include partials/head %>`  `<% include partials/header %>`  `<% include partials/footer %>`. If I remove all these three it's working. I don't understand why.

Comment: And you are running it on port 80, correct? Have you inspected the generated HTML to check if it's rendering valid HTML?

Comment: No. Port number is 8080

Comment: Yes. I've inspected them. Even including a single template is not making it work.

Comment: Please include: 1) contents of the templates 2) html source received by the browser (right click > view source) 3) what happens in the [network panel](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/network#network-panel-overview) when you hit submit, the request and its response, something like [this](http://i.imgur.com/NIFqisv.png)

Comment: @laggingreflex @Ashley Thanks for the help. I inspected the code. Actually it was inside __footer.ejs__ where there was a jQuery Code `$('form').submit(function(){ // with a switch case by default it was returning false })` It's solved now.

Comment: Please post your solution as a proper answer. You can then even accept it.